# Trouble sending an generated jsPdf to server

Tags: javascript, php, jspdf

I have generated an PDF using **jsPdf** and **Html2Canvas**. It works very well, and is downloadable.

I'm now aiming to get the generated `.pdf` saved to my server, so I can send it out via phpmailer. This is how I approached this.

```
function print() {
    document.getElementById("out").textContent = document.getElementById("fader").value;
    const filename = 'DHC_Herren_Front.pdf';

    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#pdf')).then(canvas => {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 298, 211, function () {
            var blob = doc.output('blob');

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('pdf', blob);

            $.ajax('/st/tda/dhc/men_front/upload.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
        });

    });
}
```

and my **upload.php**

```
<?php move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'],
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/st/tda/dhc/men_front/test.pdf");
?>
```

My Question would be, why I end up without an File on the Server. I feel like there must be an simple solution to this, but I just can't pinpoint it.

Newest HTML

```
       function ma() {
       document.getElementById("out").textContent = document.getElementById("fader").value;


            html2canvas(document.querySelector('#pdf')).then(canvas => {
                    var pdf = btoa(doc.output());
                    pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 298, 211,);


$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/st/tda/dhc/men_front/upload.php",
  data: {data: pdf},
}).done(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});

            });


 }
```

Newest upload.php

```
   <?php
   if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
    // print_r($data);
   file_put_contents( "test.pdf", $data );
   } else {
   echo "No Data Sent";
   }
   exit();
```

Comment: Do you get any error message output by the script? Have you checked your web server's error logs?

Comment: From where the Phpmailer comes into the picture?

Comment: From where `move_uploaded_file()` is called. I suspect permission error.

Comment: move_uploaded_file(), at least as of now (once again Newb ^^) is called by simply opening the upload.php in an new tab. (didn't copy that, because it seemed unimportant.) I rechecked the permissions on my folder. It should be allowed to write on there. :/

Comment: The phpmailer-Bridge I will cross, once I get there. For now I figured I should deal with the more pressing matter, of saving something, I can later attach, on to the Server.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: The Javascript runs through without error, and I just checked my server Errorlogs. Nothing. I have absolutly no Idea. :/

Comment: Where is doc coming from? And why create a fileName variable? And why is contentType false? Should not be set at all I would think? And what is processData doing??

Comment: I redefined my Code somewhat, based on yours guys suggestions. Also got rid of the ContentType and fileName Var. Sadly still no cigar. My Permissions are properly set.  Is there anything you can see, that is not properly executed here? Because I feel like the code cannot possibly be more efficent, without opening another whole can of worms.

Comment: Can you just echo out  $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'] and $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/st/tda/dhc/men_front/test.pdf"); on 2 separate lines and see what it says? I have a feeling that your path is wrong or does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. Take a look and see if you can adapt it to your code. This is the uploadFiles.php that the ajax sends the file to.

```html
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; // a directory separator
$cid = $_POST["cid"]; // directory name passed from the form as a variable
$rid = $_POST["rid"]; // directory name passed from the form as a variable

$storeFolder = "../recordFiles/".$cid."/".$rid; // the place where i want to save stuff

// run only if there are files sent from ajax.
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
 
    // check if the directory exists and if not then create it.
 if (!file_exists('../recordFiles/'.$cid."/".$rid)) {
  mkdir('../recordFiles/'.$cid."/".$rid, 0777, true);
 }
 
    // get the temp file name
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 
 // remove all whitespace in the file name
 $cleanedFileName =  $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $cleanedFileName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $cleanedFileName);
 
    // set the target path
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ).$ds.$storeFolder.$ds;
     
    // set the target file name and path
    $targetFile =  $targetPath.$cleanedFileName;
 
    // move the files
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
   
}

?>
```